# How can I iterate over array data and create new row for every new data in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a stream data that I call through `axios.get` and the `resposne.data` is a json with one sensor's data like `,{"Temperature":"56"},` with this I use to create a row in vue template.The `resposne.data` is assigned to array but its not appending rows ,the data in table are getting changed.

This is the template part

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Tabular Data</h1>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
          <thead>
              <tr>

                  <th class="text-center">Time</th>
                  <th class="center">Device Parameter</th>
                  <th class="center">Magnitude</th>
                  <th class="right">Unit</th>     
              </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>


                  <tr v-for="data in Tabular" :key="data">
                    <td> {{new Date().toString()}} </td>
                    <td class="test-left">Temperature</td>
                    <td class="text-center"> {{data.toString()}} </td>
                    <td class="test-left">C</td> 

                  </tr>

                  <!-- <td>{{data_alias.Humidity}}</td>
                  <td>{{data_alias.Pressure}}</td> -->  

          </tbody>

      </table>

  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import axios from 'axios';
export default {

    name: 'tabular',
    data() {

        return {
            Tabular:[ ],

        }
    },


    mounted() {
        setInterval(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data')
            .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            this.Tabular=response.data; 

        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });

    },2000);//I used set interval to get data from stream constantly
 },

}
</script>
```

Comment: looks like you are not adding the newly fetched values to your array but changing the complete array on every data fetch with `this.Tabular=response.data; `. Instead of equating, you need to add to the array.

Comment: Yes i got the point,thanks @mcy

Answer (score 1):

are you sure `Tabular` fill at one even?
I think no, because `this.Tabular=response.data;` ;

this.Tabular is `undefined` ;

try this

```
var that = this;
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data')
            .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            that.Tabular=response.data; 

        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: he's using arrow function, so he could access `this`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are replacing the content of `this.Tabular`. You should loop through your response data and, considering `response.data` is an array of rows, use

```
response.data.forEach((row) => { this.Tabular.push(row) })
```